# Multi touch Gesture - Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to get number of touch events while using `GestureDetector` class in Flutter.

I want to know how to apply both pan and scale gesture to a component/s in a stack.

Comment: We need more information on what you have attempted to do already and the code that you used. Please check the guidelines on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have tried to used ```matrix_gesture_detector``` available on flutter pub. Using that library i was able to achieve everything i needed but it gets applied on whole page altogether which I don't want for my app. I tried solutions given on this link ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536275/flutter-how-to-implement-rotate-and-pan-move-gesture-for-any-container``` but there are missing example for a gist on that link.