# How to use Draggable and InteractiveViewer together in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In Flutter, I can use Draggable to drag an object, say an image. Also, using InteractiveViewer, I can pinch-zoom the same image. Am able to do these actions separately with the individual widgets, but not able to figure out how to do both together -

1. Load image
2. Pinch-zoom out to shrink the image
3. Drag the above image to another location in the screen

How can I achieve this in Flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to scale an image (zoom in/out), you don't have to use `InteractiveViewer`. You can use `GestureDetector` to do scaling, rotating, and moving, all at once.

You can check out my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67514210/1032613).